# How do you upload image into database in Code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I've been trying to upload an image to my database (Note: I'm using Codeigniter 3) but every time I try to upload the image to the database it doesn't store it's filename and the image itself and only stores 1 bit in BLOB var type.

```
$photo = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name];
this->db->select('*')

[...]

if(empty($response){

   $data['entry_phone_no'] = $this->input->post('phone_no');
   $data['entry_email'] = $this->input->post('email');
   $data['entry_firstname'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
   $data['entry_lastname'] = $this->input->post('last_name');
   $data['entry_photo'] = $photo;
   $data['entry_photo_name'] = $photo;
```

In my model.php I have the setup above and it saves the other data (the phone num, email etc). I know I am missing some code at the `"$photo"` part but can anyone please point it out?

Comment: Do you want to store whole image into database or just store the name of the image and point that to some folder located on server?

Comment: I want to store the whole image into the database because I will display it again later

Comment: If you store the filename and store actual image into some folder than also you can display the image

Comment: I'm trying to save it into my uploads folder right now but its not appearing in the folder

Comment: I will help you if you want to upload into the folder

Comment: What details do you need to help me? I really want to figure this out already huhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the image on folder called "Uploads" and save that filename into database as below:

Views.php:

```
<input class="my-set_3" type="file" name="chatbot_profile" id="chatbot_profile" required>
```

Controller.php:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['chatbot_profile']['name']))
{

  $config['upload_path']          = './uploads';
  $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size']             = 1000000;
  $config['file_name']           =  time();
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('chatbot_profile'))
  {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
  }
  else
  {
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
      $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'] ;
      // Store this filename into database
      // Your database code will be placed here
      // OR call model  mathod from here
  }
}
```

> Note: uploads folder will created by us and outside the application
>   folder.

Comment: do i have to create a separate table for the images? my database table is currently set like:

First Name - Last Name - ID - Photo

Comment: No you don't have to create the new table.Use  $data['entry_photo_name'] = $file_name and remove $data['entry_photo'] field as we store image into uploads folder

Comment: Hello, I've already made the controller.php file. How do you call the model?